# Insert Plain Text into file ubuntu using command line

Tags: php, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have xx file into ubuntu machine and I trying to access this file through php script and insert plain text into it . 
to insert text into this file I used bash file which contain this code

```
 echo $1>> xx
```

this script will get text which wanted to be insert as parameter and insert it into 
xx file

to run bash file I used this code in php

```
      header('Content-type: text/plain') ;

           echo  $txt = 'hello \n how are you \n ';

 shell_exec ("sudo /bin/bash  /etc/freeradiusbash/append.sh  '".$txt."'");
```

I want to print hello in first line and how are you in second line but the content of xx file is

```
hello \n how are you \n
```

how can I tell bash file to print text as plain text

Comment: use double quotes instead of simple quotes

Comment: Does using double quotes help? `$txt = "hello \n how are you \n";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: I used double quotes but without result

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -e "Top line \nBottom line"
Output:  Top line
         Bottom line
```

Without the -e flag, the \n will be preserved as text.

Answer (score 0):

First, change `echo $1>> xx` to `echo "$1">> xx`, then change

```
echo  $txt = 'hello \n how are you \n ';
```

to

```
echo  $txt = "hello \nhow are you\n";
```